# how to return row count of mysql sub query

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT games.id, games.GameTitle FROM games 
WHERE EXISTS (
              SELECT filename FROM banners 
              WHERE banners.keyvalue = games.id 
                AND banners.filename LIKE '%front%'
             )
```

which is not quite correct for my use

what I'd like is something like:

```
SELECT games.id, games.GameTitle 
FROM games WHERE EXISTS (
    COUNT(SELECT filename FROM banners 
    WHERE banners.keyvalue = games.id AND banners.filename LIKE '%front%') > 1
    )
```

i.e. only select when the subquery retrieves more than 1 row.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply like that :

```
SELECT games.id, games.GameTitle 
FROM games 
WHERE (
    SELECT COUNT(filename)
    FROM banners
    WHERE banners.keyvalue = games.id AND banners.filename LIKE '%front%'
) > 1
```

Comment: @Mike since the selection was on `filename` in the original query, I kept that. @Alex glad I could help :=

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT games.id, games.GameTitle 
    FROM games 
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT COUNT(filename) 
                      FROM banners 
                      WHERE banners.keyvalue = games.id 
                          AND banners.filename LIKE '%front%'
                      HAVING COUNT(filename)>1)
```